# How do I reconstruct 3D points from rectified images at different horizontal and vertical positions?

Tags: opencv, math, computer-vision

I am familiar with reconstruction of 3D points from stereo rectified pairs. The equations for calculating coordinate estimates are:

```
Z = fB/D
X = uZ/f
Y = vZ/f
```

Where f = focal length, B = baseline, D = disparity, (u,v) are the 2D projected image coordinates.

Say I now have four cameras in a 2x2 grid. I have identified and matched fiducial markers in each image. I now want to estimate 3D point position from these projected points.

My question has two parts:
1) How does the triangulation equation change when images are not on the same horizontal baseline?
2) How do I derive an estimate from multiple pair-wise estimates?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is *triangulation*. A good starting point is to read the [paper](https://perception.inrialpes.fr/Publications/1997/HS97/HartleySturm-cviu97.pdf) by Hartley and Sturm. There is a nice [implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/triangulate.html) in MATLAB's image processing toolbox, a number of googlable others out there, and, finally, it's not hard to write one's own on the basis of the abovementioned paper.